# when using spool how to remove the blank spaces where the the column has null values. I am using Toad and Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle11g, toad

I am trying to spool the data of a table into a CSV file.There are white spaces where the column has null values. how to remove that.

```
SET COLSEP ,
SET PAGESIZE 5000
SET WRAP OFF
SET HEADSEP OFF
SET UNDERLINE OFF
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
SET TRIMOUT ON
SET LINESIZE 5000
SET TERMOUT OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF

SPOOL C:\oracle\emp1.csv
SELECT * FROM emp1

SPOOL OFF

Emp_No,Emp_name,Project_Id,Group_Id,Department,Department_Id
                  1000,        AAA,      F123,          B768,           ,       68976
                  1001,         BBB,         F222,      B897,                   ,       98689
```

Comment: here not able to post the exact output, but the output I am getting is column1 value plus 3 tab spaces and then column 2 values and so on.Also the column which has NULL value also takes 3 tab spaces. How to trim that? I have searched many site but of no use

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use `[SQLcl][1]`  to create a CSV file.

```
SET SQLFORMAT CSV

SPOOL file.csv

SELECT * FROM T;

SPOOL OFF
```

HOWTO Blog by the PM Manager of SQL*Developer ( thatJeffSmith-Oracle )

http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2015/02/a-quick-4-1-trick-set-sqlformat/ http://dbdude.net/oracle-sqlcl-use-sqlcl-to-simply-export-via-set-sqlformat-csv-and-import-via-load/

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer,but I dont have any other option other than Toad. Any idea with Toad

Comment: did you try trim function ?

Comment: if I use the below code I am getting the desired output but I am getting the||','|| after each column heading, how to remove that

SET PAGESIZE 1000
SET WRAP OFF
SET HEADSEP OFF
SET UNDERLINE OFF
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
SET TRIMOUT ON
SET LINESIZE 5000
SET TERMOUT OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF

SPOOL c:\oracle\extract\emp.csv

SELECT empno || ',' ||
       ename || ',' ||
       job || ',' ||
       mgr || ',' ||
       TO_CHAR(hiredate,'DD-MON-YYYY') AS hiredate || ',' ||
       sal || ',' ||
       comm || ',' ||
       deptno
FROM   emp
ORDER BY ename;

SPOOL OFF

SET PAGESIZE 14

Comment: anybody else who can help ?